# Laravel composer install error

Tags: laravel, centos, php-7

Hi I create server on Centos 7. i am used php 7 and Httpd server. But when i running composer install am i getting this error. any idea?

```
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-bz2.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-sqlite3.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-xml.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-zip.ini
    - /etc/php.d/30-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php.d/30-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlite.ini
    - /etc/php.d/30-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php.d/30-xmlreader.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Comment: Its quite simple, Complete the requirements of the laravel, Issues will resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install all laravel php requirements first.

You have to install this requirements exactly to php7.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation

Comment: this can help you? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-install-mcrypt-php-extension-on-centos-7-0-x64